# C# ConfigurationManager - Subsections?

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

Can anyone explain to me how to work with subsections in ConfigurationManager .config file?

This is what I've tried so far (not working):

Here is my .config:
http://pastebin.com/kxYGnD2j (sorry, I'm struggling with the code format)

Main.cs:
http://pastebin.com/mWggzbD4

Thanks!

**------EDIT-------**

Got it! "SectionGroup" was what I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup.aspx

Only had to change the .config, my Main.cs was perfectly fine!

Thanks guys!!!

P.S. I cannot self-answer right now, gonna do it in 6 hours.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what's actually happening in your code?

Comment: Can you please give more information on what you want to work with subsection?Did you mean, you want to get the subsection?

Comment: I want to have a subsection "enUS" in the "Language"-section and assign the value of key "LabelRepositoryPath" in "Language/enUs" to a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! "SectionGroup" was what I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup.aspx

Only had to change the .config, my Main.cs was perfectly fine!

Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the reference to NameValueSectionHandler in the config file. It should be as follows: `type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,System"` Everything else looks fine.